# first-letter pseudo element overriding higher specificity rules

Tags: css

In the following example and code snippet, I see the `first-letter` pseudo-element is overriding other selectors with higher specificity. The way I have beat the pseudo-element is using a higher specificity selector. See the `.blue` list item.

```
li.blue::first-letter
```

I am trying to figure why this is the case. I tried based on the [css3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter) using

```
list-style-position: inside
```

but that did not yield the desired effect.

What am I missing here?

```css
/* 0002 */
li::first-letter {
  color: orange;
  background-color: black;
}

/* 0011 */
li.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}

/* 0011 */
li.green {
  color: green;
  background-color: #454564;
}

/* 0011 and 0012 */
li.blue,
li.blue::first-letter {
  color: blue;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <li class="red">RED</li>
    <li class="green">GREEN</li>
    <li class="blue">BLUE</li>
  </ul>
</main
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Appears to do exactly it is suppose to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a specificity issue. You are simply dealing with different elements here - granted, one of them is just a pseudo element, but still.

Specificity only comes into play when several rules are matching the same element(s) - not the case here.

It is pretty much the same as if you had the following:

```css
html .red { /* html in front to increase specificity */
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}

.first-letter { /* replaced pseudo element with a class and a "real" element here */
  color: orange;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"><span class="first-letter">R</span>ED</div>
```

Now here you would not expect the formatting of the outer element to "override" that of the inner either, right?

Comment: Ok. I get it. The spec talks about the fictional tag associated with the first-letter. for eg: <li::first-letter>
T
</li::first-letter>. Hence they are not targeting the same elements and specificity does not apply here. Did I get that right? https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#application-in-css

Comment: Yes, exactly. By definition/per specification pseudo elements (not only `::first-letter`, but also f.e. those created via `::before`/`::after`) have to behave as if they were _real_ child elements existing in the DOM, although they aren't actually (that's what makes them "pseudo" in the first place.)